# Horizontal Scroll Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want my scrollbar to auto-position to my clicked button inside of my div. Code  below

HTML:

```html
<div class="headmenu">
  <div class="divdivitems">
    <a class="ui button" id="cat1" onclick="myCat(this.id);">
      <img src="../css/images/fishiii.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
    <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth bordergray bgwhite" id="cat2">
      <img src="../css/images/porki.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
    <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth bordergray bgwhite" id="cat3">
      <img src="../css/images/beefi.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
    <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth bordergray bgwhite" id="cat4">
      <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
    <a class="ui button" id="cat5">
      <img src="../css/images/saladi.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
    <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth bordergray bgwhite" id="cat6">
      <img src="../css/images/pasta.png" class="heightwidth padding5">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
       Headmenu has position:fixed, overflow-x:auto and overflow-y:hidden.
       Divdivitems has 750px width specified overflow-y:hidden and position:relative

I tried using

```
$('#cat5').click(function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#headmenu').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
          }, "fast");
       });
```

But it's not working. I want my scrollbar to horizontally position on my clicked button, category. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `margin-left` use `.scrollLeft(400);` and `.scrollTop(400);`.

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/9k0wyzod/

Comment: I want my div's scrollbar to autoposition depending on button clicked in my upper div.. Is this what this code is doing, I'm sorry if i explained it poorly on my post. Also if possible i'd like to use scrolling with animation thanks

Comment: I've updated the link above with a better Fiddle to help you. Note that this now uses jQuery, so if you don't want to use that, we'll have to do it another way. Also 400 is hardcoded in there. You may want to figure out how far to scroll and use that figure.

Comment: oh this is what I need. But i can't make it work atm.. I'll keep on trying tho.. Could i get some more help. Basically what i have is a div with a div(that allows scrolling) that contains 6 categories separated by a few pixels each. Everytime i click a certain button I want the horizontal scroll of that div to positioon depending on the button clicked. The position being hardcoded is fine. Thanks.

Comment: If you're familiar with jQuery, you'll need a click event on each of your buttons like I have (`.click` function). In the function that you pass to the click method, you find the div that you want to scroll (`$` function) and call '.scrollLeft' on that, passing the number of pixels you want to scroll. It's pretty much all there in that Fiddle.

Comment: could u please check what is wrong with this. http://jsfiddle.net/ziddo/vjx97ho1/

Comment: The problem with this is the scrollLeft was on the wrong div. Try this and it should work: `$('#dvmain').scrollLeft(200);`

Comment: yes that made it work.. Did it yesterday. Thanks still tho. I am currently using hardcoded numbers and the scrolls are proper for only a specific android screen resolution.. I still can't use scrollto(element). Anyway thank you.